# JAXB to xml adds xml version tag

Tags: xml, jaxb, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

In mule anypoint studio, when I use a custom tranformer to create a jaxb object then marshall it to xml using the JAXB to xml component I get the resulting xml with the xml version tag below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

So the resulting xml then looks like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ExampleXML>
</ExampleXML>
```

This wouldn't usually be a problem but at this point I then add the xml to a soap envelope.

The result being

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <ExampleXML>
    </ExampleXML>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Which is an invalid request..

Is there same way to set the jaxb to xml transformer to not add this header?

Comment: How are u adding the xml to soap envelope? Are u using XSLT transformer?

Comment: I've tried to use xslt transformer but can only return the value of the xml. How would I select and return the entire xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try XSLT transformer which looks similar to this. This xsl:copy basically copies the nodes matching with the expression. Here '.' refers to current node and in fact root node is the current node here. Hence entire XML gets embedded inside SOAP envelope.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
     <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you invoke the marshaller you can set the fragment property to true which will not generate the header.

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
```

Comment: That would work if I was marshalling in java code however I'm using the jaxb to xml mule component to marshall the jaxb object.